# How to preload Cataclysm without pre-ordering it?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I pre-load or pre-download Cataclysm without pre-ordering it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can start the Digital Download as if you'd ordered online by following the steps below. You will not be able to access new Cataclysm content until you activate your account with a purchased Cataclysm key after midnight PST 12/7 of course.

1. Make sure both WoW and the launcher and background downloader are not running.
2. Navigate to your World of Warcraft\WTF folder on your computer.
3. Open the Launcher.wtf file in your text editor of choice.
4. Change the "accountType" entry from 'LK' to 'CT'
5. Open the Config.wtf file and repeat step 4.
6. Open the WoW Launcher, you should begin downloading roughly 700 MB of data.

Enjoy!